# Does Microsoft exposed "Microsoft Remote Desktop client" APIs for Android and iOS

Tags: android, ios, rdp

Does Microsoft exposed "Microsoft Remote Desktop client" APIs for Android and iOS ? Which I can embed into my Android and iOS applications to connect remote desktop.

Currently I have installed "Microsoft Remote Desktop client app", I want similar behavior in my apps. 
[Microsoft Remote Desktop client](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn473009(v=ws.11).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

I didn't found any good source on Microsoft Remote Desktop Client API.
I'm not sure about this API, but it seems rather good option. Free Remote Desktop protocol implementation.

1. [Git Repo](https://github.com/FreeRDP/FreeRDP)
2. [Official Site](http://www.freerdp.com/)

Hope this helps.